# How to restrict frame range for multiple F-curves at once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, fcurves

I have lots of f-curves(~100) cycle modifier applied to and I want to restrict same frame range for all of them simultaneously. is it possible to make it? coz I feel pain to restrict same frame range for all curves manually. thank u guys in advance!

[image]

Comment: scripting. Try scripting